# How to dynamically add components to grid?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I created a grid using `v-for`. I need to add components to each column I created, each one in seperate column. I created `view` in script, where I store components but still I can't add them to each column separately:

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row dense>
      <v-col
        v-for="n in 2"
        :key="n"
        :cols="n === 1 ? 2 : 10">

          <v-card outlined tile>
             <component :is="view"></component>
          </v-card>

      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import XYZ from '../views/XYZ.vue';
import AAA from '../views/AAA.vue';

export default {
  name: 'Project',
  data: {
      view: 'dynamic_views', 
  },
  components: {
    'dynamic_views': {
      XYZ,
      AAA
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the components directly inside the `components` option then create a data property called `componentNames` which you should loop through it :

```js
import XYZ from '../views/XYZ.vue';
import AAA from '../views/AAA.vue';

export default {
  name: 'Project',
   data:{
      componentNames:['XYZ','AAA']
  },
  components: {
      XYZ,AAA
   
  },
};
```

in template :

```html
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row dense>
      <v-col
        v-for="(comp,n) in componentNames"
        :key="n"
        :cols="n === 1 ? 2 : 10">

          <v-card outlined tile>
             <component :is="comp"></component>
          </v-card>

      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: Ok, in my real app components are called differently, let's say XYZ and AAA. How can I loop through them? I can't use `view_${n}`. I changed my example to new components names.

Comment: please check my edited answer

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. `v-for` doesn't create columns

Comment: Ok, I've found a solution - instead of using `data: {}` you need to use `data() {}`. Don't know why but it works now. And also enumeration starts with 0, not 1 so needed to change a condition to `:cols="n === 0 ? 2 : 10"`